# Customizing response code on uncaught exception in Roo

Tags: exception, spring-roo, http-response-codes

I have a Roo-based application.

If an exception got thrown from my controller, my application will render a stack trace to the end user, but the response will have the status code of 200.

How can I customize this so that any uncaught exception will result in a response with code 500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `webmvc-config.xml` set `defaultStatusCode` property on `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`.

Example:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultStatusCode">
        <value>500</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```